# WebSraping Error! AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am still new to this python coding thing, I am trying some web scraping codes and I am stuck on this error
it worked fine for the first page until I started to try and scrape the next pages

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, datetime, time

# adjusting the link and the header (only change the user agent)
url = "https://www.amazon.eg/s?k=mechinical+keyboard&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=nb_sb_noss_1"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}

def get_data(soup):
    page = requests.get(url, headers= headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , "html.parser")

    # getting the html code of the webpage
    title = soup.find_all("span", "a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal")
    price = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "a-price-whole"})

    # making a list for the data to be saved in
    title_list=[]
    price_list=[]

    # for loops to extract the titles and prices
    for titlex in title:
        titles= titlex.text
        title_list.append(titles)

    for pricex in price:
        prices=pricex.text.strip()
        prices = prices[:-1]
        price_list.append(prices)

##
def get_nextpage(soup):
    pages = soup.find('a', {'class': "s-pagination-strip"})
    if not pages.find({'class':'s-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-disabled'}):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.eg/-' + str(pages.find({'class': 's-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator'}).find('a')['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return
    
    
while True:
    data = get_data(url)
    url = get_nextpage(data)
    if not url:
        break
    print(url)
```

That is the error I keep getting, I think I am writing the find() wrong I cant figure out how to properly write it for the "a" tag

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[85], line 43
     41 while True:
     42     data = get_data(url)
---> 43     url = get_nextpage(data)
     44     if not url:
     45         break

Cell In[85], line 33, in get_nextpage(soup)
     32 def get_nextpage(soup):
---> 33     pages = soup.find('span', {'class': "s-pagination-strip"})
     34     if not pages.find({'class':'s-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-disabled'}):
     35         url = 'https://www.amazon.eg/-' + str(pages.find({'class': 's-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator'}).find('a')['href'])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: `get_data` `return`s nothing, therefore automatically `None`. It should return `soup`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks it worked, but now I get another error for 
`if not pages.find({'class':'s-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-disabled'}):`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, datetime, time

# adjusting the link and the header (only change the user agent)
url = "https://www.amazon.eg/s?k=mechinical+keyboard&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=nb_sb_noss_1"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "DNT": "1", "Connection": "close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}


def get_data(url):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    # getting the html code of the webpage
    title = soup.find_all("span", "a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal")
    price = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "a-price-whole"})

    # making a list for the data to be saved in
    title_list = [titlex.text for titlex in title]
    price_list = [pricex.text.strip()[:-1] for pricex in price]

    return soup

def get_nextpage(soup):
    pages = soup.find('span', {'class': "s-pagination-strip"})
    if not pages.find({'class': 's-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-disabled'}):
        try:
            url = 'https://www.amazon.eg/-' + str(pages.find('a',
                {'class': 's-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator'}).get('href'))
            return url
        except AttributeError:
            pass

while True:
    data = get_data(url)
    url = get_nextpage(data)
    if not url:
        break
    url = url.replace('en/en', 'en')
    print(url)
```

output:

```
https://www.amazon.eg/-/-/en/s?k=mechanical+keyboard&page=2&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&qid=1682303405&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=sr_pg_1
https://www.amazon.eg/-/-/en/s?k=mechanical+keyboard&page=3&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&qid=1682303407&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=sr_pg_2
https://www.amazon.eg/-/-/en/s?k=mechanical+keyboard&page=4&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&qid=1682303409&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=sr_pg_3
https://www.amazon.eg/-/-/en/s?k=mechanical+keyboard&page=5&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&qid=1682303411&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=sr_pg_4
https://www.amazon.eg/-/-/en/s?k=mechanical+keyboard&page=6&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&qid=1682303413&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=sr_pg_5
https://www.amazon.eg/-/-/en/s?k=mechanical+keyboard&page=7&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&qid=1682303415&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=sr_pg_6
```

Things to Note:

1. you need to pass `url` as a parameter to the function `get_data(url)` instead of `get_data(soup)`.
2. Handle the exception `AttributeError` if the class `s-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator` is not found.
3. handle the URL from the 2nd page onwards as it starts getting an extra `en` in the URL which makes it an invalid URL:
   `https://www.amazon.eg/-/-/en/en/s?k=mechanical+keyboard&page=3&language=en_AE&crid=1UBHQ81JZMC5G&qid=1682303529&sprefix=mechinical+keyboard%2Caps%2C206&ref=sr_pg_2`. So remove/replace that extra `en` to make it a valid one.